# How to encode an authorization request_uri

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I need to construct a custom request_uri for an implementation of Spring OAuth2.  **What specific code should be used to properly encode each of the parameters in the request_uri?**

The full, unencoded, `request_uri` is as follows, but is resulting in an error that indicates that a token is not granted:

```
http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme  
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code  
&state=13ab71ae-c8ed-4370-a60f-dd7fe47ed763
```

As you can see, the individual parameters are:

```
client_id=acme  
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login  
response_type=code  
state=13ab71ae-c8ed-4370-a60f-dd7fe47ed763
```

And the code that was used to construct the above request_uri is:

```
CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) attr.getRequest().getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
String attrToken = csrf.getToken();
authorizationRequest.setState(attrToken);
String newRequestUri = "http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?";
String clientId = authorizationRequest.getClientId();
newRequestUri = newRequestUri + "client_id=" + clientId;
String redirectUri = authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri();
newRequestUri = newRequestUri + "&redirect_uri="+redirectUri;
Set<String> respTypes = authorizationRequest.getResponseTypes();
String respType = respTypes.iterator().next();//this plucks the first one, but is not safe for when there is a list.
newRequestUri = newRequestUri +"&response_type="+respType;
String state = authorizationRequest.getState();
newRequestUri = newRequestUri + "&state="+state;
attr.setAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri", newRequestUri, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
//now re-set the request attributes to reflect the changes we just made
RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attr);
```

**More specifically, this OP asks what syntax should be used to encode the following string values in the code above: `newRequestUri`, `clientId`, `redirectUri`, `respType`, and `state`.**

The [Official OAuth2 Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) says you can use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-Type and `UTF-8` encoding, but then also gives this example:

```
/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3
&state=xyz
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb
```

Similarly, the [Spring OAuth2 Developer Guide](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) only contains one use of the word `encode`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for what is commonly called [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or URL-encoding. There are functions for this in almost every language's HTTP library, either for a single value or for a set of key-value pairs.

In practice `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is [almost the same as URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  I guess I was looking for Java syntax to do the encoding.  I got pulled into other tasks today, but I intend to revisit this later.